# Java database driver not found, even though it's in the jar file

Tags: java, sql-server, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I have a Java application that connects to a SQLServer database, and it is intended to run at the commandline.  In the maven dependencies I have added the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run the program via Intellij, I am able to run it with no issues.  When I take the jar file that is created and crack it open, I can see the JTDS driver:

[image: jar file expanded]

However, when I try to run the jar at the commandline with the exact same arguments that I used in the Intellij run configuration, I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://databaseserver:1433/database
```

The command I run is

```
java -jar jarname.jar -cfg ../config.xml
```

This doesn't seem to be related to this particular driver, as I have the same issue if I connect to an Oracle database and include the Oracle thin driver dependency instead.  (However, just to make things fun, if I add a Postgres driver dependency, it runs just fine on the command line connecting to a Postgres database.)

If I manually add the driver jar (same version as the maven dependency) to the classpath, the jar does run properly.

What could be causing the driver inside the jar to not be on the classpath? (Or is there something else that could be causing the issue?)

Comment: Did you register the driver?

Comment: @MadProgrammer You shouldn't need to do that any more (at least if your driver is [jdbc 4.0](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/10/whats-new-in-jdbc-40.html#driver-and-connection-management) or up).  Since v4 was released in 2007, I hope that's a safe assumption.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Got any other ideas? Since they've tried three drivers and only one works, my guess is not...

Comment: @MadProgrammer You are correct. IMO, OP should upgrade to a more recent sql server driver; the [jTDS home page](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) says (in part) *jTDS is an open source 100% pure Java (type 4) JDBC 3.0*, so pre-4.0

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are correct! I did not register it - I didn't think I needed to because I thought that it was a JDBC 4.0 driver, but your question made me double check and in fact the JTDS driver is JDBC version 3.0, which doesn't auto register drivers just by being on the classpath.  That would also explain why it worked for Postgres (JDBC 4.0) but not with the JTDS driver.  This resolved the issue for me!  I wish I could mark your comment as correct.

Comment: Feel free to auto answer, cause I wasn't aware the JDBC 4 drivers auto registered (oh, how much I would give to work on a real database system again :()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MadProgrammer's comment above was the issue: I had not registered the driver, since I hadn't realized that it was a JDBC 3.0 driver, not JDBC 4.0.